# What is the next number in this sequence: $1, 2, 6, 24, 120$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was playing through No Man's Sky when I ran into a series of numbers and was asked what the next number would be.

$$1, 2, 6, 24, 120$$

This is for a terminal assess code in the game no mans sky.  The 3 choices they give are; 720, 620, 180

Comment: What was the purpose of the question?

Comment: @Battani I was trying to figure out what the next number in the sequence was.

Comment: I wanna to ask your question then saw your asnwer,so that i asked)

Comment: @Atom: it seems like you already knew the answer when asking your question, because you answered very quickly…!

Comment: @Watson I did when I posted this, I was going to ask this last night but decided to work through it first and ended up solving it. When I saw that neither the question nor answer were on here already I selected the "answer your own question" option when posting the question. That way the question would be available online and I would instead be contributing instead of asking for an answer and providing a hodgepodge of behind the scenes work I was doing. I can delete this if that's not the proper way of doing it!

Comment: @Atom: no problem! I was just surprised by the quickness of your answer ;-)

Comment: http://oeis.org is a good resource.  [A search](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C+2%2C+6%2C+24%2C+120&language=english&go=Search) gives several hundred possibilities, but you'd want to go with the most comprehensible.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

After some testing I discovered that these numbers are being multiplied by their corresponding number in the sequence.

For example:

```
1 x 2 = 2
2 x 3 = 6
6 x 4 = 24
24 x 5 = 120
```

Which would mean the next number in the sequence would be

```
120 x 6 = 720
```

and so on and so forth.

Edit: Thanks to @GEdgar in the comments for helping me make pretty cool discovery about these numbers. The totals are also made up of multiplying each number up to that current count.

For Example:

```
2! = 2 x 1 = 2
3! = 3 x 2 x 1 = 6
4! = 4 x 3 x 2 x 1 = 24
5! = 5 x 4 x 3 x 2 x 1 = 120
6! = 6 x 5 x 4 x 3 x 2 x 1 = 720
```

Comment: Look up "factorial" on the web to find out more.

Comment: Notice what happens if you go downward: You have $720$ and divide by $6$, getting $120$.  Then divide by $5$, getting $24$.  Then by $4$, getting $6$, then by $3$, getting $2$, then by $2$, getting $1$, then by $1$, getting $1$.  Which shows that the factorial of $0$ is $1$.  Why the factorial of $0$ is $1$ is something people often find puzzling. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Is 0 usually universally considered the factorial of 1? Or is this an exemption where once you get that low that part of the sequence is ignored since it seems odd that 0 is the factorial of 1 and you just start with 1 instead?

Comment: @Atom : $0$ is _not_ the factorial of $1$; rather, $1$ is the factorial of $0$: $$ \begin{align} 0! & = 1 \\  1! & = 1 \\ 2! & = 2 \\ 3! & = 6 \\ 4! & = 24 \\ 5! & = 120 \\ 6! & = 720 \\ \text{etc.}  \end{align} $$

Comment: to understand 0!: n! = the nth derivative of x^n.  x^0=1, and taking zero derivatives of 1 leaves 1; so 0!=1.

Comment: @aml to understand 0!: The sum of an empty set is defined to be 0, and the product of an empty set is defined to be 1. 0! would be an empty product, thus 1.

(Compare also to disjunction of an empty set is false, conjection of an empty set is true)

Comment: @Atom Or you could use what you found before you edited your own answer, and apply your method backwards... (it gives some interesting things if you keep going backwards even further too!)

Answer (score 36):

The next number is $840$.  The $n$th term in the sequence is the smallest number with $2^n$ divisors.

Er ... the next number is $6$.  The $n$th term is the least factorial multiple of $n$.

No ... wait ... it's $45$.  The $n$th term is the greatest fourth-power-free divisor of $n!$.

Hold on ... :)

Probably the answer they're looking for, though, is $6! = 720$.  But there are *lots* of [other justifiable answers!](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C6%2C24%2C120&sort=&language=&go=Search)

Comment: Woah! Online encyclopedia of integer sequences?! That's amazing. You're right about that. When asked the question originally I was given a few pre-selected answers, I should have taken note and included those to narrow down the options, didn't realize just how many sequences there were!

Comment: It's a gem of a reference.  Very, very helpful site!

Comment: @BernardMasse Having been expected to be able to figure out the next number, there is, logically, a logical method to finding the next number, as trial and error won't get you far, as you can see by the size of $720\dots$

Answer (score 2):

The next number is 720.

The sequence is the factorials:

1 2 6 24 120 = 1! 2! 3! 4! 5!

6! = 720.

(Another way to think of it is each term is the term before times the next counting number.

T0 = 1; T1 = T0 * 2 = 2; T2 = T1 * 3 = 6; T3 = T2 * 4 = 24; T4 = T3 * 5 = 120; T5 = T4 * 6 = 720.

Comment: it's yet done. Please find another answer , a little bit original :) perhaps with the sum of the digits ? note also that it begins with 1 2 and ends with 120. Perhaps its an opportunity to concatenate and add zeroes. Good luck

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  Glad to have you here contributing.  I invite you to check out the [MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to make the typesetting for your answers all mathy and stuff.